Exporting a NetworkX graph to graphml raises "GraphML does not support type <class 'type'> as data values."
I have .dot file like so mwe.dot
digraph "VS-GH-Graph" {
    graph [name="VS-GH-Graph"];
    "Users/user0"   [_id="Users/user0",
        _key=user0,
        _rev="_hzGd4vu---",
        avatar_url="",
        bio="My bio",
        blog="",
        collaborators=11,
        company="",
        created_at="2009-07-27T18:53:24Z",
        disk_usage=678928,
        email=None,
        events_url="https://api.github.com/users/user0/events{/privacy}",
        followers=79,
        followers_url="https://api.github.com/users/user0/followers",
        following=248,
        following_url="https://api.github.com/users/user0/following{/other_user}",
        gists_url="https://api.github.com/users/user0/gists{/gist_id}",
        hireable=True,
        html_url="https://github.com/user0",
        id=109167,
        location=Here,
        login=user0,
        name="MyName",
        node_id="MDQ6VXNlcjEwOTE2Nw==",
        organizations_url="https://api.github.com/users/user0/orgs",
        owned_private_repos=73,
        plan="{'name': 'pro', 'space': 976562499, 'collaborators': 0, 'private_repos': 9999}",
        private_gists=2,
        public_gists=3,
        public_repos=38,
        received_events_url="https://api.github.com/users/user0/received_events",
        repos_url="https://api.github.com/users/user0/repos",
        site_admin=False,
        starred_url="https://api.github.com/users/user0/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
        subscriptions_url="https://api.github.com/users/user0/subscriptions",
        total_private_repos=7,
        twitter_username=user0,
        two_factor_authentication=True,
        type=User,
        updated_at="2024-04-15T20:40:59Z",
        url="https://api.github.com/users/user0",
        visit_started_at="2024-05-07T08:16:14Z"];
    "Users/user1"   [Type=ShadowUser,
        _id="Users/user1",
        _key=user1,
        _rev="_hzGd5G2---"];
    "Users/user1" -> "Users/user0"  [key=0,
        _from="Users/user1",
        _id="FOLLOW/user1-user0",
        _key="user1-user0",
        _rev="_hzGd5K----",
        _to="Users/user0"];
    "Users/user2"   [Type=ShadowUser,
        _id="Users/user2",
        _key=user2,
        _rev="_hzGd5NG---"];
    "Users/user2" -> "Users/user0"  [key=0,
        _from="Users/user2",
        _id="FOLLOW/user2-user0",
        _key="user2-user0",
        _rev="_hzGd5QO---",
        _to="Users/user0"];
    "Users/user3"   [Type=ShadowUser,
        _id="Users/user3",
        _key=user3,
        _rev="_hzGd5TW---"];
    "Users/user3" -> "Users/user0"  [key=0,
        _from="Users/user3",
        _id="FOLLOW/user3-user0",
        _key="user3-user0",
        _rev="_hzGd5XG---",
        _to="Users/user0"];
    "Users/user4"   [Type=ShadowUser,
        _id="Users/user4",
        _key=user4,
        _rev="_hzGd5aO---"];
}

which looks like

I'm trying now to get a graphml file so I did
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import read_dot
nx_g = read_dot("mwe.dot")
nx.write_graphml_lxml(nx_g, "mwe.graphml")

but it raises
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\graphml.py:455, in GraphML.get_xml_type(self, key)
    454 try:
--> 455     return self.xml_type[key]
    456 except KeyError as err:

KeyError: <class 'dict'>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 nx.write_graphml_lxml(nx_g, "gh.graphml")

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py:770, in argmap.__call__.<locals>.func(_argmap__wrapper, *args, **kwargs)
    769 def func(*args, __wrapper=None, **kwargs):
--> 770     return argmap._lazy_compile(__wrapper)(*args, **kwargs)

File <class 'networkx.utils.decorators.argmap'> compilation 9:5, in argmap_write_graphml_lxml_5(G, path, encoding, prettyprint, infer_numeric_types, named_key_ids, edge_id_from_attribute)
      3 import gzip
      4 import inspect
----> 5 import itertools
      6 import re
      7 import warnings

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\graphml.py:176, in write_graphml_lxml(G, path, encoding, prettyprint, infer_numeric_types, named_key_ids, edge_id_from_attribute)
    165 except ImportError:
    166     return write_graphml_xml(
    167         G,
    168         path,
   (...)
    173         edge_id_from_attribute,
    174     )
--> 176 writer = GraphMLWriterLxml(
    177     path,
    178     graph=G,
    179     encoding=encoding,
    180     prettyprint=prettyprint,
    181     infer_numeric_types=infer_numeric_types,
    182     named_key_ids=named_key_ids,
    183     edge_id_from_attribute=edge_id_from_attribute,
    184 )
    185 writer.dump()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\graphml.py:746, in GraphMLWriterLxml.__init__(self, path, graph, encoding, prettyprint, infer_numeric_types, named_key_ids, edge_id_from_attribute)
    743 self.attribute_types = defaultdict(set)
    745 if graph is not None:
--> 746     self.add_graph_element(graph)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\graphml.py:779, in GraphMLWriterLxml.add_graph_element(self, G)
    777     self.attribute_types[(str(k), "graph")].add(type(v))
    778 for k, v in graphdata.items():
--> 779     element_type = self.get_xml_type(self.attr_type(k, "graph", v))
    780     self.get_key(str(k), element_type, "graph", None)
    781 # Nodes and data

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\graphml.py:457, in GraphML.get_xml_type(self, key)
    455     return self.xml_type[key]
    456 except KeyError as err:
--> 457     raise TypeError(
    458         f"GraphML does not support type {type(key)} as data values."
    459     ) from err

TypeError: GraphML does not support type <class 'type'> as data values.


I don't understand why such an error occurs.
Any idea?
